# Передать параметры в браузер

Tags: python

Есть алгоритм программы:

1. Ввести адрес размещения браузера.
2. И с помощью **webbrowser.open** открыть в браузере вкладку.

Но тут возникают проблема передачи параметра, программа открывает вкладку в стандартном браузере и выводит ошибки:

Введи адрес браузера: /Chrome Incognito.exe/

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Ніколя\Desktop\Новая папка\Portable Chrome 4.0.201.1 Dev\2.py", line 6, in

```
subprocess.check_output([webbrowser.open('vk.com', path)])
```

File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 607, in check_output
    with Popen(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs) as process:

File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1085, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)

File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 663, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg

TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Сам код программы:

```
import webbrowser
import os, sys
import subprocess

path = input("Введи адрес браузера: ")
subprocess.check_output([webbrowser.open('vk.com', path)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Опции 1 и 2 у вас взаимоисключающие: либо вы запускаете браузер, как программу, используя `subprocess`, либо вы запускаете браузер, используя `webbrowser` модуль.

Чтобы открыть адрес в стандартном браузере (по возможности в новой вкладке):

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Чтобы открыть адрес в выбранном браузере, например `Chrome`:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.get('Chrome').open(url)
```

Если хочется передать дополнительные опции командной строки, то можно `%s` включить в строку, тогда переданное имя интерпретируется как полная командная строка, где на месте адреса веб-страницы находится `%s`. Либо использовать `subprocess` модуль напрямую:

```
 import subprocess

 subprocess.call([r'...\chrome.exe', url])
```